# How can I check csrf-cookie while processing GET request?

Tags: python, django, django-csrf

For some architectural reasons I have to use csrf-token verification with GET requests.
First I've tried top user @csrf_protect decorator from Django. 
so, this code:

```
class MyView():

    @method_decorator(csrf_protect)
    def get(self):
    ...
```

But this approach causes an error:

```
TypeError at /home/
_wrapped_view() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)
```

in `/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py in _wrapper, line 25`

Also as far as I can see, it can work only with POST requests.
So how can I check csrf cookie when handling GET method?

Comment: are you trying to read the CSRFToken in your view?

Comment: @Chris Hawkes I want to implement csrf-verification as mas as possible 'on common way'. I've some investigation in django code and found that csrf-verification algorithm is that we just compare csrf-token from cookie and from form input. But with my GET request I pass some params and I don't want to include csrf-token into GET-params. So I am a little bit confused with founding any ways to implement some csrf-protection in this case.

Comment: do you just want to check for the existence of the token in the cookie?  CSRF protection works by verifying that the token passed in the request matches the one generated by the server.  If you aren't passing one in, then you aren't really doing anything.  Also, CSRF shouldn't come into play for GET requests.  Furthermore, they should explictly NOT be included in GET requests: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/36671/csrf-token-in-get-request

Comment: so it seems unnecessary what you're trying to do.  CSRFTokens are created and stored on the client's computer as soon as the view is rendered.  You should be able to extract this value from HttpRequest.COOKIES['CSRFToken'] on your view, but I'm only guessing since I haven't personally done it.